# Which classifier to choose in NLTK

Tags: nlp, classification, nltk

I want to classify text messages into several categories like, "relation building", "coordination", "information sharing", "knowledge sharing" & "conflict resolution". I am using NLTK library to process these data. I would like to know which classifier, in nltk, is better for this particular multi-class classification problem.

I am planning to use Naive Bayes Classification, is it advisable?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Naive Bayes is the simplest and easy to understand classifier and for that reason it's nice to use. Decision Trees with a beam search to find the best classification are not significantly harder to understand and are usually a bit better. MaxEnt and SVM tend be more complex, and SVM requires some tuning to get right.

Most important is the choice of features + the amount/quality of data you provide!

With your problem, I would focus first on ensuring you have a good training/testing dataset and also choose good features. Since you are asking this question you haven't had much experience with machine learning for NLP, so I'd say start of easy with Naive Bayes as it doesn't use complex features- you can just tokenize and count word occurrences.

EDIT:
The question [How do you find the subject of a sentence?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6448002/how-do-you-find-the-subject-of-a-sentence/6448053#6448053) and my answer are also worth looking at.

Comment: Thanks alot for the answer. I am classifying SMS text messages and the language very informal (obviously) around 50% of the words are OOV(out of vocabulary)so I have normalized those SMS into proper English text with around 15-20% OOV using Moses statistical Machine Translation tool. Do you recommend any other way to normalize these text messages.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot comment on text normalization as I know next to nothing about it. Maybe there are emoticon and abbreviation dictionaries? Twitter + SMS are really hard!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Training a Naive Bayes Classifier for each category and then labeling each message to a class based on which Classifier provides the highest score is a standard first approach to problems like this. There are more sophisticated single class classifier algorithms which you could substitute in for Naive Bayes if you find performance inadequate, such as a Support Vector Machine ( Which I believe is available in NLTK via a Weka plug in, but not positive). Unless you can think of anything specific in this problem domain  that would make Naieve Bayes especially unsuitable, its ofen the go-to "first try" for a lot of projects.

The other NLTK classifier I would consider trying would be MaxEnt as I believe it natively handles multiclass classification. (Though the multiple binary classifer approach is very standard and common as well). In any case the most important thing is to collect a very large corpus of properly tagged text messages.

If by "Text Messages" you are referring to actual cell phone text messages these tend to be very short and the language is very informal and varied, I think feature selection may end up being a larger factor in determining accuracy than classifier choice for you. For example, using a Stemmer or Lemmatizer that understands common abbreviations and idioms used, tagging part of speech or chunking , entity extraction, extracting probably relationships between terms may provide more bang than using more complex classifiers.

This paper talks about classifying Facebook status messages based on sentiment, which has some of the same issues, and may provide some insights into this. The links is to a google cache because I'm having problems w/ the original site:

http://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&q=cache:_AeBYp6i1ooJ:nlp.stanford.edu/courses/cs224n/2010/reports/ssoriajr-kanej.pdf+maxent+classifier+multiple+classes&hl=en&gl=us&pid=bl&srcid=ADGEESi-eZHTZCQPo7AlcnaFdUws9nSN1P6X0BVmHjtlpKYGQnj7dtyHmXLSONa9Q9ziAQjliJnR8yD1Z-0WIpOjcmYbWO2zcB6z4RzkIhYI_Dfzx2WqU4jy2Le4wrEQv0yZp_QZyHQN&sig=AHIEtbQN4J_XciVhVI60oyrPb4164u681w&pli=1

Comment: Thanks alot for the answer. yes I am classifying SMS and the language very informal (obviously) around 50% of the words are OOV(out of vocabulary)so I have normalized those SMS into proper English text with around 15-20% OOV using Moses statistical Machine Translation tool. Do you recommend any other way to normalize these text messages.