# natural language query processing

Tags: c#, nlp, artificial-intelligence

I have a NLP (natural language processing application) running that gives me a tree of the parsed sentence, the questions is then how should I proceed with that.

```
What is the time
\-SBAR - Suborginate clause
  |-WHNP - Wh-noun phrase
  | \-WP - Wh-pronoun
  |  \-What
  \-S - Simple declarative clause
   \-VP - Verb phrase
     |-VBZ - Verb, 3rd person singular present
     | \-is
     \-NP - Noun phrase
       |-DT - Determiner
       | \-the
       \-NN - Noun, singular or mass
         \-time
```

the application has a build in javascript interpreter, and was trying to make the phrase in to a simple function such as

```
function getReply() {
   return Resource.Time();
}
```

in basic terms, what = request = create function, is would be the returned object, and the time would reference the time, now it would be easy just to make a simple parser for that but then we also have what is the time now, or do you know what time it is. I need it to be able to be further developed based on the english language as the project will grow.

the source is C# .Net 4.5

thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are asking how to identify semantically equivalent questions like "what is the time?" and "do you know what time it is?", then it is a fairly difficult problem. solving the general case will require quite a bit of research effort (before the actual deployable coding work starts).

Comment: Yes, I am rewritting a AIML based AI engine, that has been in development for 2+ years, the problem is research is all that has been done, however i am still unable to see what the best way to tackle this would be.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. I will try my best to answer. I doubt any answer on SO will be able to provide a good solution to this problem in its generality, but for simple queries, let me try to help :)

Comment: Thanks, anything that will kick start it will be good, since it has to have a stable foundation upon which it is based.

Comment: The answer to the question "natural language query processing" is "madly violet". But seriously, what is your question in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see, using **dependency parse trees** will be more helpful. Often, the number of ways a question is asked is limited (I mean *statistically significant variations are limited* ... there will probably be corner cases that people ordinarily do not use), and are expressed through words like *who*, *what*, *when*, *where*, *why* and *how*.

Dependency parsing will enable you to extract the nominal subject and the direct as well as indirect objects in a query. Typically, these will express the basic intent of the query. Consider the example of tow equivalent queries:

1. What is the time?
2. Do you know what the time is?

Their dependency parse structures are as follows:

```
root(ROOT-0, What-1)
cop(What-1, is-2)
det(time-4, the-3)
nsubj(What-1, time-4)
```

and

```
aux(know-3, Do-1)
nsubj(know-3, you-2)
root(ROOT-0, know-3)
dobj(is-7, what-4)
det(time-6, the-5)
nsubj(is-7, time-6)
ccomp(know-3, is-7)
```

Both are *what*-queries, and both contain "time" as a nominal subject. The latter also contains "you" as a nominal subject, but I think expressions like "do you know", "can you please tell me", etc. can be removed based on heuristics.

You will find the [Stanford Parser](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/lex-parser.shtml) helpful for this approach. They also have [this online demo](http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/parser/), if you want to see some more examples at work.

Comment: thanks, im not using the standford parser but a modified/rewritten OpenNLP, but you did spark an idea, which i can query in to.

Comment: OpenNLP, I am afraid, does not have dependency parsing. [The answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5556778/opennlp-is-there-a-way-to-get-the-subject-of-a-sentence-using-opennlp) confirms my fear.

Comment: Sorry, ment SharpNLP which is a translation of OpenNLP, but i believe it does. if not, just an extra task on the list.

Comment: Haha, i know, I wanted something simple that i could work from, call it a barebone, as in this question, just need a place to start from.